# ls -al output column fields

Tags: linux, unix

Can someone guide me what does each column of `ls -ali` output in linux describe?

Comment: `man ls` will tell you. See the section on _The Long Format_

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ls -ali

something like this

```
 67403780 -rw-------.  1 root root   1114 12月  6 2016 anaconda-ks.cfg
```

-a, --all
              do not ignore entries starting with .

-i, --inode
              print the index number of each file

inode, authority, num ,user,group, size , date    file name

you can use  "man ls" see more infomations

Answer (score 0):

`ls -ali` combines the options `-a`, `-l` and `-i`.

From the [official documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed):

> ```
> -l
> ```
>
> In addition to the **name of each file**, print the **file type**, **file mode bits**, **number of hard links**, **owner name**, **group name**, **size**, and **timestamp**

In addition to the aforementioned fields, `-i` adds the **index number of each file**.

Finally, option `-a` includes all the file with names starting with `.`, which otherwise would be considered hidden and thus ignored .